# Using environment variables with application.yml in SvelteKit project

Tags: yaml, environment-variables, svelte, sveltekit

I'm working in a SvelteKit project, and we want to remove hardcoded secrets from `application.yml`. Problem is, I'm not 100% sure how to environmentalize these values and use them in the `application.yml`.

I can't find any specific guides that are applicable to my current use case. Currently the `application.yml` is stored in `projectRoot/app/src/main/resources/application.yml`. I tried creating a `values.yml` in the same directory, and setting up the secrets like:

```
secrets:
  secret1: secretValue
  secret2: secretValue
  ...
```

and then referencing them in `application.yml` like `{{secrets.secret1}}` per a guide I found, though that guide was either out of date or applicable to other use cases, because this did not work.

There is a `.env` file in `projectRoot/frontend/.env`. Do I just need to put the secrets in there, and then reference them in `application.yml` a different way? Or is my `values.yml` approach valid and I just don't know how to reference it correctly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you using the secrets? And what are you using the application.yml for?

Comment: The application.yml contains info pertaining to backend setup, and the secrets in question are security keys for different services.

Comment: So you are directly using the secrets inside your backend? and I'm assuming SvelteKit is your backend, then you can simply load the secrets directly in your backend without exposing your secrets